# How can I make grease pencil be effected by shadow?

Tags: light, grease-pencil, shadows

I'm using grease pencil in surface draw mode to make my scene look painted, but I'm not sure how to make grease pencil respond to shadowing. I know grease pencil can't cast shadows, so I set my geometry to shadow catcher and to not render in viewport or render, but my grease pencil is still lit up behind other objects. How can I make my grease pencil respond to shadows? (I tested with both EEVEE and cycles.)